# Calling a subclass's getter in Swift

Tags: properties, swift, subclassing

So, while playing around with Swift, I ran into this issue and it's boggling my mind.

I have a class Card:

```
class Card {
    var contents = ""
    var chosen = false
    var matched = false

    var description: String {
    get {
        return self.contents
    }
    }

    func match(otherCards: Card[]) -> Int {...}
}
```

and a class PlayingCard that subclasses Card:

```
class PlayingCard: Card {
    var suit: Suit
    var rank: Rank

    override var contents: String {
    get {
        return "\(rank.description())\(suit.toRaw())"
    }
    set { }
    }

    init(rank: Rank, suit: Suit) {
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank

        super.init()
    }

    override func match(otherCards: Card[]) -> Int {...}
}
```

As you can see, in Card, the `description` property is computed from the `contents` property. However, when I instantiate a PlayingCard, I have a computed `contents` property that overrides the stored `contents` property of Card. However, if I call my PlayingCard's `description`, it returns the Card's stored `contents`, not PlayingCard's computed, actual `contents`.

```
func testPlayingCardProperties() {
    var card = PlayingCard(rank: .Ace, suit: .Spades)

    XCTAssert(card.contents == "A♠️", "Contents not overriden.") // TRUE
    XCTAssert(card.description == "A♠️", "Description not overriden.") // FALSE??
}
```

What's going on? Note that

```
func testCardProperties() {
    var card = Card()
    card.contents = "Test Card"

    XCTAssert(card.contents == "Test Card", "Contents getter error.") // TRUE
    XCTAssert(card.description == "Test Card", "Description getter error.") // TRUE
}
```

works as expected.

**UPDATE**

I ran the following in Playground... and it worked. Still no luck outside of it.

```
class Card {
    var contents = ""
    var chosen = false
    var matched = false

    var description: String {
    get {
        return contents
    }
    }

    func match(otherCards: Card[]) -> Int {
        var score = 0

        for card in otherCards {
            if card.contents == contents {
                score += 1
            }
        }

        return score
    }
}

enum Suit: String {
    case Diamonds = "♦️"
    case Hearts = "♥️"
    case Spades = "♠️"
    case Clubs = "♣️"

    static func allSuits() -> Suit[] {
        return [.Diamonds, .Hearts, .Spades, .Clubs]
    }
}

enum Rank: Int {
    case Ace = 1
    case Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten
    case Jack, Queen, King

    func description() -> String {
        switch self {
        case .Ace:
            return "A"
        case .Jack:
            return "J"
        case .Queen:
            return "Q"
        case .King:
            return "K"
        default:
            return String(toRaw())
        }
    }
}

class PlayingCard: Card {
    var suit: Suit
    var rank: Rank

    override var contents: String {
    get {
        return "\(rank.description())\(suit.toRaw())"
    }
    set { }
    }

    let maxRank = 13

    init(rank: Rank, suit: Suit) {
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
    }

    override func match(otherCards: Card[]) -> Int {
        let allCards = otherCards + [self]
        let testMatches = {
            () -> (Card, Card[])[] in

            var result: (Card, Card[])[] = []

            for i in 0..allCards.count {
                result += (allCards[i], Array(allCards[0..i] + allCards[(i + 1)..allCards.count]))
            }

            return result

            }()

        let scores = testMatches.map({
            (card, otherCards) -> Int in
            if let playingCard = card as? PlayingCard {
                var rankValue = 1.0
                var suitValue = 1.0

                for matchCard in otherCards {
                    if let matchPlayingCard = matchCard as? PlayingCard {
                        if (matchPlayingCard.rank == playingCard.rank) {
                            rankValue *= 8;
                        } else {
                            rankValue /= 2;
                        }

                        if (matchPlayingCard.suit == playingCard.suit) {
                            suitValue *= 2;
                        } else {
                            suitValue /= 2;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if rankValue >= 1.0 {
                    return Int(rankValue)
                } else if suitValue >= 1.0 {
                    return Int(suitValue)
                } else {
                    return 0
                }
            } else {
                return 0
            }
            })

        return scores.reduce(Int.min, combine: { $0 > $1 ? $0 : $1 });
    }
}


var card = PlayingCard(rank: .Jack, suit: .Spades)
card.description
```

Could this just be an Xcode bug?

Comment: The documentation merely says that `self` "is exactly equivalent to the instance itself". Perhaps it's a bug? [File it!](http://bugreport.apple.com)

Comment: Does it work if `contents` is computed in both classes?

Comment: We could really use an example that we could paste complete into a playground and reproduce the problem—as you can see from my answer, I've tried to create a minimal reproducing example and got the "right" result from it.

Comment: Okey, I have taken the implementation of `Suit` and `Rank` from the Apple guide and applied it to your code. The only problem I had was because the character `♠` used there for suits doesn't match character `♠️` you used in the `XCAssert`. Otherwise the code works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be something odd, and likely buggy, going on. If I take this code:

```
class Base {
    var contents = "Base contents"
    var description: String {
    get {
        return self.contents
    }
    }
}

class Derived : Base {
    override var contents: String {
    get {
        return "Derived contents, dynamically generated"
    }
    set { }
    }
}

let d = Derived()
println(d.contents) 
println(d.description)
```

...and put it in a single file (in a playground or on in a command-line OS X app), then the output is as follows (and I think, as expected):

```
println(d.contents) // Prints "Derived contents, dynamically generated"
println(d.description) // Prints "Derived contents, dynamically generated"
```

However, if I move out the Base class into "base.swift" and the Derived class into "derived.swift", leaving the main code in its own file, *making no other changes*, then it prints out:

```
println(d.contents) // Prints "Derived contents, dynamically generated"
println(d.description) // Prints "Base contents"
```

...which feels like a bug to me.

Comment: `d.contents` works, but OP's point is that `d.description` does not work as expected.

Comment: @jtbandes Just edited: My d.description is the same as my d.contents. Is that not what's expected?

Comment: That seems to be different from the results OP sees, as shown in the `XCTAssert` results

Comment: @jtbandes Yeah, that's what I thought. Perhaps the OP can play "spot-the-difference" from this point, or discover something by reducing his code to something more similar to my example. It's a little hard when there's not enough code in the original question for a standalone reproduction.

Comment: I added my playground code above. Funnily, it works just fine in playground. In my project the playground code is split into two files, a Card.swift with just the Card class, and a PlayingCard.swift with everything else. If you can reproduce in a Swift project, it might just be a bug?

Comment: Also, I ran @MattGibson's code in Xcode, and it resulted in the same issue ([link](http://imgur.com/AK1nX5n)), so I'll probably file a bug.

Comment: @jtbandes Here's interesting: If I put my code all in the same file, I get the results as I said. If I separate out my Derived and Base classes into different files—if that's the *only* change I make—then I get Atharv's result: my `println(d.description)` prints "Base contents".

Comment: Updated my answer with my latest observation.

Comment: This is fixed in the latest Xcode, by the way (tested with 6D532l, Xcode 6.3 beta 2)